# Как сделать using для статического класса

Tags: c#

Есть статический класс `Helper`. Хочу использовать его из другой формы, однако мне приходится вызывать его через `Helper.Val`. Можно ли как то сделать `using Helper;` и потом просто вызывать `Helper`

```
public static class Helper
{
    public static double Val(string data)
    {
        return Convert.ToDouble(data.Replace(".", ","));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Можно вот как.

В начале файла

```
using static YourNamespace.Helper;
```

и в коде просто

```
double v = Val(data);
```

(Обратите внимание, не просто `using`, а `using static`.)

Работает, начиная с C# 6 (Visual Studio 2015).

Comment: спасибо )!!!!!!!!!

Comment: @Teraro: Пожалуйста!